# Unable to override XMLHttpRequest using pageMod (Firefox addon)

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I have some troubles trying to override the **XMLHttpRequest** from a Firefox addon context.

The reason why I want to override this function is that I want to know when a certain request is made in order to fire one of my event.

The **main.js** I am currently using:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.example.com",
    contentScriptWhen: "start",
    attachTo: ["top"],
    contentScriptFile: data.url("js/script.js"),
});
```

And here is the **script.js**

```js
var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, uri, async, user, pass) {
  alert("working");
  oldOpen.call(this, method, uri, async, user, pass);
};
// This request is for an example purpose it is not in my real script
var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open("GET", "", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I noticed that when I replaced **XMLHttpRequest** by **unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest** the requests was no longer working.

- How come this script does not work as I would like ?
- Is it related to the scope of my addon ?

*Thanks for you concernment.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PageMod scripts run in a [sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox) that have a different view on objects (aka. [xrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Xray_vision)).
Depending on how exactly you define them a content page cannot either access those objects or get security exceptions if it tries to invoke functions.

Accessing the `unsafeWindow` is the correct approach, but you still have to export your wrapper function into the target page context via [exportFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.exportFunction).

Basically, every single function that content can invoke must be exported.
Objects must either be clonedInto or created in the target compartment, e.g. via `new unsafeWindow.ArrayBuffer(1024)` to create a buffer in content - based on the content's unsafe constructor - instead of the sandbox.

Checking the toolbox console for security exceptions may prove useful.

Edit:

The code should roughly look like this, minor modifications might be necessary, I haven't tested it:

```
let wrapped = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
let wrapper = function(){wrapped.apply(this,arguments) } // might need to waive xrays on this or the arguments?
unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = exportFunction(wrapper,unsafeWindow)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I understood the concept of privileged code. I exported all the functions I needed then I used the unsafeWindow object. Here is my new [code](http://jsfiddle.net/z2qsqb9y/). Out of curiosity, Why when I replace unsafeWindow.old = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open by unsafeWindow.old = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open the callback works but it does not want to recall the old method using the old variable ? It's like if the old variable has been altered.

Comment: you can just use local variables. no need to use `defineAs` or assigning intermediate values to the unsafe window